# Expanding Rust Lifetime

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have a bit of code that I'm fighting with. It's a little helper function that should return a `Vec<&str>` to the calling function. I can't seem to get the lifetime right, though.

Here is the code snippet:

```rust
fn take_symbol<'a>(ch: &'a str, current: &'a mut String) -> &'a mut TokenList<'a> {
    let out = TokenList::<'a>::new();

    out.push(current.as_str());
    out.push(ch);

    *current = String::new();

    &mut out
}
```

The compiler is telling me: `error: 'out' does not live long enough` and that the reference must be valid for the lifetime of `'a`, but it looks to me like it is defined for `'a`.

I have also tried changing it to:

```rust
let out = &mut TokenList::<'a>::new();
```

which doesn't change any of the error messages. Or:

```
let out = &'a mut TokenList::<'a>::new();
```

which the compiler doesn't like at all.

How do I define `out` to have a lifetime of `'a`?

For further details, here is my definition of TokenList:

```rust
pub type Token<'a> = &'a str;
pub type TokenList<'a> = Vec<Token<'a>>;
```

Comment: In short, lifetimes only describe how long something lives, never influence how long it lives.

Comment: Too bad. That would be a nice feature. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The lifetime of `out` is not `'a`, since `out` is destroyed at the end of the function. Rust will not allow you to return a reference to it (it would allow accessing freed memory!).

Try changing your function to the following:

```
fn take_symbol<'a>(ch: &'a str, current: &'a mut String) -> TokenList<'a> {
    let out = TokenList::<'a>::new();

    out.push(current.as_str());
    out.push(ch);

    *current = String::new();

    out
}
```

This way you will pass the ownership of `out` to the caller and it will live long enough.

Comment: Ahhh, I feel dumb. For some reason, I was thinking of `&str` as something like a string and a wrapper even though the `&` clearly indicates it is a reference. Now that I've made your correction, it is pretty clear I need to go back through and redefine my initial datatype and propagate that change through my code. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! I guess feeling dumb is a clear effect of learning :P... especially when learning Rust!