# How to create a struct with a vector of references?

Tags: reference, rust, lifetime

Rust seems like such an optimal language - I should've known fighting the compiler would be the price. I'm trying to create a constructor for a struct, and I'm getting `does not live long enough` errors.

Distilled to the barest of bones, I have:

```
fn main() {
    println!("RUST PLEASE");
}

struct Help<'a> {
    list: Vec<&'a Traits>
}

impl<'a> Help<'a> {
    fn new() -> Help<'a> {
        Help { list: vec![&Test] }
    }
}

trait Traits {
    fn mice(&self);
}

struct Test;
impl Traits for Test {
    fn mice(&self) { print!("WHY"); }
}
```

So, I'm doing this because that vector `list` is supposed to hold a list of trait objects. It (supposedly) holds heterogeneously any class that implements the supplied trait. As I understand it, that means I have to use references so the vector has a real size to work with. And since it's a reference, the lifetime has to be there to ensure they live and die together.

The thing is, I know what's wrong. In `new`, that `Test` belongs in the `new` scope, and I try to pass its reference up and out of the function. If I do that, `Test` goes out of scope and the reference is bad. So what do I do? How can I get the object to last the lifetime of `Help`? After all, there's really no one to own it.

Also, if anybody has any tips in general on how to return references out of a function in general, I'd be very happy to hear them.

**EDIT** This is not the same as simply passing up ownership of the object; I can't do that because the vector *needs* a reference instead of an object on the stack. The answer by Simon is probably what I'm looking for - I had forgotten I could box things up like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expanding Rust Lifetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252851/expanding-rust-lifetime)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably don't actually want to return references out... but you could box them instead and have them own the boxed value:

```
fn main() {
    println!("RUST PLEASE");
}

struct Help {
    list: Vec<Box<Traits>>
}

impl Help {
    fn new() -> Help {
        Help { list: vec![Box::new(Test)] }
    }
}

trait Traits {
    fn mice(&self);
}

struct Test;
impl Traits for Test {
    fn mice(&self) { print!("WHY"); }
}
```

Your `Help` struct then owns a vector of boxed values that you can then reference going forward.

[Playpen link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=fn%20main()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22RUST%20PLEASE%22)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Astruct%20Help%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20list%3A%20Vec%3CBox%3CTraits%3E%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aimpl%20Help%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20new()%20-%3E%20Help%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Help%20%7B%20list%3A%20vec!%5BBox%3A%3Anew(Test)%5D%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atrait%20Traits%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20mice(%26self)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Astruct%20Test%3B%0D%0Aimpl%20Traits%20for%20Test%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20mice(%26self)%20%7B%20print!(%22WHY%22)%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D&version=stable)